# PostgreSQL filter by column with json

Tags: postgresql

There is a json_agg resulting in `[10,20]` or `[null]`. I want to filter all rows with `[null]` in the column. How is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE jsoncol::text = '[null]'
```

Comment: Then i get this error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = json
LINE 78: ) x WHERE x.geometry = '[null]'::json
                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 3910

Comment: @Dalitos: you will need to use `jsonb` for that (on both sides)

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution: jsoncol ->>0 IS Null

Comment: That would also be true for a JSON like `[null,42,"x"]`.

Comment: hm, do you have another solution?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.